# Select values from table having a field value same as another field value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following columns in a table : FDA_ID and FDA_ID_PARENT and the following set of data:

```
FDA_ID  | FDA_ID_PARENT
 771    |   NULL
 772    |   771
 773    |   771
 774    |   0
 775    |   NULL
 776    |   775
 777    |   NULL
```

I have the FDA_ID = 773 as entry data and want to get those 'linked' to it.

What I mean by linked is those FDA_ID having the same FDA_ID as the FDA_ID_PARENT of FDA_ID = 773
and those having the same FDA_ID_PARENT as the FDA_ID_PARENT of FDA_ID = 773.

So in the case of FDA_ID = 773, the query would return 
FDA_ID = 771, 772 and 773.

I have tried the below query but it does not work:

```
select *
from FDA_TABLE FDA
where 
FDA.FDA_ID = 773
or 
FDA.FDA_ID in (select FDA_ID from FDA_TABLE where FDA_ID_PARENT = FDA.FDA_ID_PARENT);
```

Any help please?

Comment: your question is  unclear provide sample data and regarding output

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin : I don't understand your comment. I did provide a sample data and give an example of what I want as output based on a given input. Thanks.

Comment: What if 772 had "children" or 771 had a "parent"? Or is your data limited to just a parent and children (not grand children/parents etc)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second part of your `WHERE` clause returns all rows that have a parent set.

```
FDA.FDA_ID in (select FDA_ID from FDA_TABLE where FDA_ID_PARENT = FDA.FDA_ID_PARENT)
```

You may want to use something like (or any parts of it):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    FDA_TABLE
WHERE
    -- self
    FDA_ID = 773
    -- parent
    OR FDA_ID = (
        SELECT FDA_ID_PARENT FROM FDA_TABLE WHERE FDA_ID = 773
    )
    -- siblings
    OR FDA_ID_PARENT = (
        SELECT FDA_ID_PARENT FROM FDA_TABLE WHERE FDA_ID = 773
    )
    -- children
    OR FDA_ID_PARENT = 773
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want really two selects?

1. You want the parent of the given FDA_ID, 773
2. You want all the FDA_ID´s which have that same parent.

I recommend using a union.

```
(select FDA_ID_PARENT from FDA_TABLE where FDA_ID=773)
union all
(select FDA_ID from FDA_TABLE where FDA_ID_PARENT=(select FDA_ID_PARENT from FDA_TABLE where FDA_ID=773))
```

Comment: @JMabee: The parentID of the given 773 is 771 in OP´s example data. In the second query I want the FDA_ID of all rows containing this 771 in the parentID, which should give me 772 and 773.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
select * 
from FDA_TABLE
where coalesce((select FDA_ID_PARENT from FDA_TABLE where FDA_ID = 773), 0) 
      in (FDA_ID, coalesce(FDA_ID_PARENT, 0))
```

If `FDA_ID_PARENT = 0` is not the same as `FDA_ID_PARENT = NULL` then change the `0`s in `coalesce()` with a value like `-1` that is not valid in the column `FDA_ID_PARENT`.
See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a79a7cccd8dbfba4f49f23c739f1e5ca).
Results:

```
> FDA_ID | FDA_ID_PARENT
> -----: | :------------
>    771 | null         
>    772 | 771          
>    773 | 771
```